# type mismatch with @helper

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to show a form with the values but it's not working.

my action:

```
public static Result login() {
    User user = new User();
    user.name = "Murilo";

    Form<User> userForm = form(User.class);

    return ok(login.render(userForm.fill(user)));
}
```

and my html:

```
@(myForm : play.data.Form[models.User])

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
     @helper.inputText(myForm("name"))
</body>
</html>
```

but when I access it, the following error throws:

```
type mismatch; found : play.data.Form.Field required: play.api.data.Field
```

Comment: Do you use/import a class from the `api` package anywhere?

Comment: No, I don't, but I tried import play.api.data in the second line of code but the same error occurrs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a addition to **nico_ekito**'s good answer: I usually do not use `@helper..` because it is long and not/less readable if your form starts to grow (more fields). So I do the following:

```
@(editForm:Form[User]

@*** IMPORTS ****@
@import helper._

@form(routes.Tasks.save(), 'class -> "form-horizontal") {
     @inputText(editForm:Form("description()").....)
     @inputArea(editForm:Form("description()").....)
}
```

Comment: Nicee, it was another doubt that I had.

Answer (score 3):

In your template, it should be:

```
@(myForm : Form[User])

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
     @helper.inputText(myForm("name"))
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `@(myForm : play.api.data.Form[models.User])`

Comment: If I do that, the following errors throws: error: method render in class login cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: Because in my class I use 'play.data.Form' and using 'play.api.data.Form' this code doest'n work: 'Form<User> userForm = form(User.class);'